# Using NodeJS Quandl API behind a proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, quandl

I'm trying to use quandl in nodejs but I'm behind a web proxy. Does somebody know how to set it up so my requests use the proxy? (http and https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Quandl NodeJS module developer (great guy) and he added proxy support to the newest release. It's already available in NPM :D